# Time-Averaged Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am curious if there is any definition or understanding of Fourier transform averaged with respect to time length to allow the transformation of non-integrable functions?

By time averaged I mean:

$F_{Tavg}({\omega}) = lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{F_{T}(\omega)}{T} = lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{\frac{-T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}e^{t\omega j}f(t)\chi_{[\frac{-T}{2},\frac{T}{2}]}dt$

This concept is somewhat used in the definition of Power Spectral Density but I am only interested in deterministic signals.